# How do I fix a missing Nsight menu in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

After installing CUDA 5.0 (release) in a trial version of Visual Studio 2010, I can create, open and compile CUDA projects. However, I cannot debug because the Nsight menu does not appear. It would normally appear between the `Team` and `Data` menus.

How can I get the Nsight menu to appear? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the trial version. The computer is running an older Windows 7 install and has had Visual Studio 2008 and CUDA installed on it in the past.

Visual Studio with an open CUDA project, created with the CUDA wizard, but with no Nsight menu:

[image: Visual Studio with an open CUDA project, created with the CUDA wizard, but with no Nsight menu]

**Update:**

After reinstalling Visual Studio, some settings, like the list of recently opened projects, carry over from the old installation. Since the old settings could be part of the problem, I tried a more thorough uninstall, where I first uninstalled CUDA, then Visual Studio, then other NVIDIA software on the machine. Then, I removed Visual Studio and all NVIDIA folders from Program Files, Program Files (x86) and Application Data. Then I searched through the registry for "Visual Studio" "VisualStudio", NVIDIA and CUDA keys and removed everything I found. Then I reinstalled Visual Studio and CUDA 5. It didn't help. Actually, it got a bit worse, because I lost the syntax highlighting for the .cu files. Creating, opening and compiling projects still worked. So, I uninstalled CUDA 5 and installed CUDA 4.2.9. That "fixed" both issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By first installing CUDA 4.2 and then installing CUDA 5.0 on top (without uninstalling CUDA 4.2), I got a working environment, where I can create, open and debug both CUDA 4.x and CUDA 5.0 projects. Syntax highlighting also works for both 4.x and 5.0 projects.

[image: Visual Studio with Nsight menu]

Comment: If I already have Nsight 3.0, CUDA 5.0 and VS2010 installed, do I need to remove any of them before installing CUDA 4.2? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. If you try it, could you add a comment here to let us know if it worked?

Comment: Yes, it's now resolved, but simply because I didn't realize you couldn't use it with VS Express.

Comment: @MiloChen: The Express versions are not officially supported, but can be made to work. You need to install the free Windows SDK and tweak some configuration files. Google for instructions.